# How to insert data to a table that includes a foreign key in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a dictionary database and want to insert words to MyList table. But the words have to exist in Words table because MyList has foreign key. I have already written a code but it returns empty object. What is the wrong with that? Or is there an another way to do it? please help

Database

```java
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \"Words\" (\n" +
                "\t\"Id\"\tINTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,\n" +
                "\t\"Name\"\tTEXT,\n" +
                "\t\"Mean\"\tTEXT\n" +
                ");");
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE \"MyList\" (\n" +
                "\t\"Id\"\tINTEGER NOT NULL,\n" +
                "\t\"Name\"\tTEXT,\n" +
                "\t\"Mean\"\tTEXT,\n" +
                "\tFOREIGN KEY(\"Id\") REFERENCES \"Words\"(\"Id\")\n" +
                ");");
```

my methods

```java
 public String InsertWordToList(DbConnection data,String kelime){

        Word yeni=null;
        SQLiteDatabase db= data.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values= new ContentValues();

        String msg;
        Boolean bool = ifExists(kelime,db);
        if(bool){
            msg= "kelime zaten var";
        }
        else {
            yeni = FindWord(kelime, db);

            if(yeni!=null){
                Log.e("yeni id",Integer.toString(yeni.getId()));
                values.put("Id", yeni.getId());
                values.put("Name", yeni.getName());
                values.put("Mean", yeni.getMean());


                db.insertOrThrow("MyList", null, values);
                msg="kelime eklendi";
            }
            else msg="kelime databasede kayırlı değil";
        }
        db.close();
        return msg;
    }

    public Word FindWord( String kelime, SQLiteDatabase db){

        Word w=null;
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Words WHERE Name = ?", new String[] {kelime});

            while (c.moveToNext()){
                w = new Word(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Id"))
                        ,c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Name"))
                        ,c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Mean")));

            }
            c.close();
            if(w!=null){
            return w;}
            else return null;
        }

    public Boolean ifExists (String kelime, SQLiteDatabase db) {

        Word w=null;
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Words WHERE Name = ?", new String[] {kelime});

            while (c.moveToNext()){
            w = new Word(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Id"))
                    ,c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Name"))
                    ,c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Mean")));
        }
        c.close();
        if(w!=null) return true;
        else return false;
    }
```